# Why am I getting a 404 status error on my PUT request?

Tags: jquery, node.js, ajax

I'm getting a HTTP 404 on a PUT request as shown below:

[image]

```
$(function(){
$("#showMovies").click(function() {
  $.ajax({
    method:"GET",
    url: "http://localhost:3000/movielist",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (response) {
      $.each(response, function(i, movie) {
        const rowText = "<tr>" +
          "<td>" + movie.idmovielist + "</td>" +
          "<td>" + movie.name + "</td>" +
          "<td>" + movie.thumbnail_path + "</td>" +
          "<td>" + movie.description + "</td>" +
          "<td>" + movie.year_released + "</td>" +
          "<td>" + movie.language_released + "</td>" +
          "<td>" + "<button button id = \"deleteMovie\" type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-danger\" data-toggle=\"modal\" data-target=\"#exampleModal\">Delete</button>" + "</td>" +
          "<td>" + "<button button id = \"editMovie\" type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-danger\" data-toggle=\"modal\" data-target=\"#exampleModal\">Edit</button>" + "</td>";
        $("#movies").append(rowText);
      });
    }
  });
});

$("#movieAdded").click(function() {
  $.ajax({
    method:"POST",
    url: "http://localhost:3000/movielist/addMovie",
    dataType: "json",
    data: {
       idmovielist: 10,
       name: 'Bubble Gum',
       thumnail_path: 'yourieiri.jpg',
       description: 'Disturbing',
       year_released: '2007',
       language_released: 'french'
    },
    success: function (data) {
      $.each(data, function(i, movie) {
        const rowText = "<tr>" +
          "<td>" + movie.idmovielist + "</td>" +
          "<td>" + movie.name + "</td>" +
          "<td>" + movie.thumbnail_path + "</td>" +
          "<td>" + movie.description + "</td>" +
          "<td>" + movie.year_released + "</td>" +
          "<td>" + movie.language_released + "</td>" +
          "<td>" + "<button button id = \"deleteMovie\" type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-danger\" data-toggle=\"modal\" data-target=\"#exampleModal\">Delete</button>" + "</td>" +
          "<td>" + "<button button id = \"editMovie\" type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-danger\" data-toggle=\"modal\" data-target=\"#exampleModal\">Edit</button>" + "</td>";
        $("#movies").append(rowText);
      });
    }
  });
});
$.ajax({
   method:"DELETE",
   url: "http://localhost:3000/movielist/8",
   dataType: "json",
   success: function (data) {
     $.each(data, function(i, movie) {
    const rowText = "<tr>" +
         "<td>" + movie.idmovielist + "</td>" +
         "<td>" + movie.name + "</td>" +
         "<td>" + movie.thumbnail_path + "</td>" +
         "<td>" + movie.description + "</td>" +
         "<td>" + movie.year_released + "</td>" +
         "<td>" + movie.language_released + "</td>" +
         "<td>" + "<button button id = \"deleteMovie\" type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-danger\" data-toggle=\"modal\" data-target=\"#exampleModal\">Delete</button>" + "</td>" +
         "<td>" + "<button button id = \"editMovie\" type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-danger\" data-toggle=\"modal\" data-target=\"#exampleModal\">Edit</button>" + "</td>";
       $("#movies").append(rowText);
     });
   }
});
$.ajax({
    method:"PUT",
    url: "http://localhost:3000/movielist/6",
    dataType: "json",
    data: {
        idmovielist: 6,
        name: 'Lion King',
        thumanail_path: 'https://lumiere-a.akamaihd.net/v1/images/',
        description: 'cartoon',
        year_realeased: '2000',
        language_released: 'english'
    },
    success: function (data) {
      $.each(data, function(i, movie) {
       const rowText = "<tr>" +
          "<td>" + movie.idmovielist + "</td>" +
          "<td>" + movie.name + "</td>" +
          "<td>" + movie.thumbnail_path + "</td>" +
          "<td>" + movie.description + "</td>" +
          "<td>" + movie.year_released + "</td>" +
          "<td>" + movie.language_released + "</td>" +
          "<td>" + "<button button id = \"deleteMovie\" type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-danger\" data-toggle=\"modal\" data-target=\"#exampleModal\">Delete</button>" + "</td>" +
          "<td>" + "<button button id = \"editMovie\" type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-danger\" data-toggle=\"modal\" data-target=\"#exampleModal\">Edit</button>" + "</td>";
        $("#movies").append(rowText);
      });
    }
});
});
```

So whenever I try to execute my put request I always get this error of status code 404 not found and also My get post and delete are working just fine it is just my put request what can I do to fix it. Also I was able to get this working n my web browser because I forgot to add a function

```
app.put('/movielist/id',(req,res) =>{
let update = req.body;
mysqlConnection.query("UPDATE movielist SET year_released = '2000' WHERE idmovielist = '6'",
[update.year_released, update.idmovielist,req.params.id],
(err, results)  => {
    if (!err) {
      res.send("Movie list is updated");
    } else {
      console.log(err);
    }
});
});
```

Also my post request code

```
app.post('/movielist/addMovie',(req, res) => {
   mysqlConnection.query("INSERT INTO movielist (idmovielist, name, thumnail_path, description, year_released,language_released) VALUES ('10', 'Bubble Gum', 'yourieiri.jpg', 'Disturbing', '2007', 'french');",
   req.body,
   (err,rows) => {
     if (!err) {
       res.send("Movie is added");
     } else {
       console.log(err);
     }
  });
});


  app.get('/movielist',(req,res)=> {
    mysqlConnection.query("SELECT * FROM movielist", (err, rows,fields)=> {
      if (!err) {
        res.send(rows);
      } else {
        console.log(err);
      }
    });
  });
 app.delete('/movielist/:id',(req,res) => {
    mysqlConnection.query("DELETE FROM movielist WHERE idmovielist = ?",[req.params.id],(err,rows,fields) =>{
      if (!err) {
        res.send("Movie is deleted");
      } else {
      console.log(err);
    }
    });
  });
app.post('/movielist/addMovie',(req, res) => {
   mysqlConnection.query("INSERT INTO movielist (idmovielist, name, thumnail_path, description, year_released,language_released) VALUES ('10', 'Bubble Gum', 'yourieiri.jpg', 'Disturbing', '2007', 'french');",
   req.body,
   (err,rows) => {
     if (!err) {
       res.send("Movie is added");
     } else {
       console.log(err);
     }
  });
});
app.put('/movielist/:id',(req,res) =>{
let update = req.body;
mysqlConnection.query("UPDATE movielist SET year_released = '2000' WHERE idmovielist = '6'",
[update.year_released, update.idmovielist,req.params.id],
(err, results)  => {
    if (!err) {
      res.send("Movie list is updated");
    } else {
      console.log(err);
    }
});
});
```

[Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PkZxM.png)

Comment: If you recieve a 404, that's a server-side problem (provided that the URLs requested by the client-side are correct). So without knowing what's going on on your server-side, it's hard to tell.

Comment: Maybe you can share the code for the backend.

Comment: Updating without sending any parameters to the URL?

Comment: @vahdet  app.put('/movielist/id',(req,res) =>{
let update = req.body;
mysqlConnection.query("UPDATE movielist SET year_released = '2000' WHERE idmovielist = '6'",
[update.year_released, update.idmovielist,req.params.id],
(err, results)  => {
    if (!err) {
      res.send("Movie list is updated");
    } else {
      console.log(err);
    }
});
});

Comment: @vahdet that is my put request on the back end

Comment: Please add it into the question body with proper formatting, it's not solely for me, for everybody encountered the question.

Comment: @vahdet I posted it already

Comment: For backend are you using nodejs with express framework?

Comment: @boobanos yes I am

Comment: Also guys is there any way I can make my UI look nicer and pretty

Comment: @Adil Ali I think you are doing something wrong in lines :  let update = req.body;
mysqlConnection.query("UPDATE movielist SET year_released = '2000' WHERE idmovielist = '6'",
[update.year_released, update.idmovielist,req.params.id],

Comment: @Adil Ali , If its possible also share the backend code for POST request so that we can compare and Check

Comment: @Ajinkya I will post it

Comment: @Ajinkya I added it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to change this:

```
app.put('/movielist/id',(req,res) =>{
```

to this:

```
app.put('/movielist/:id',(req,res) =>{
```

In nodejs with express framework, in order to use /link/*parameter*/, *parameter* needs to be declared with **:**.

Comment: I still get that 404 error even when I do fix it in my backend

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Error</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <pre>Cannot PUT /movielist/6</pre>
    </body>
</html>

Comment: If after this change postman returns this then the problem is probably due to some bad routing. Can you post more of your backend code? Not whole functions, just your app.put(link), app.get(link) declarations?

Comment: I posted my get post put and delete

Comment: This seems to work for me. Are you sure postman is returning that result after the changes?

Comment: @boobsnos so the put method worked for you can you show me please

Comment: @AdilAli The endpoint is created just fine. Can you post a screenshot from postman when you make a PUT request for /movielist/id ?

Comment: Try deleting both "/:id" from server and "/id" from url when you make the request and restart the server. It seems like the endpoint is not created at all. What version of express are you using?

Comment: 4.16.4 this is the one I am using

Comment: What was the problem after all?

Comment: I guess I had to restart the server

Comment: Backend code always needs the server to be restarted, to apply any changes. Frontend on the other side (your jquery code) runs inside the browser so each time you refresh the page, the code is executed again. Since you are using NodeJS I recommend looking into [nodemon](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemon) tool. It is a handy tool that auto restarts the server for you, if you change anything in your code. (Also please mark my answer as accepted if it helped you :) )

Comment: so is their a way I can make a post and put request without making changes to my backend like try to make the changes to the front end itself

Comment: @AdilAli I am not sure what you mean. Can you rephrase your question perhaps with an example?